# 400 Bad request upload file SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, file-upload, windows-application

When I am trying to upload a file using `FileCreationInformation`, I am getting a http 400 bad request error at the `context.executequery()` call.

I can upload the file successfully using `SaveBinaryDirect` with `MemoryStream` or `FileStream`, but the uploaded file doesn't have any content/data.

Code using `SaveBinaryDirect`:

```
string siteUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my-site/";
string username = "xx@yy.com";
string password = "ss@sf";
string filePath = "filePath.xlsx"

using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securePWD);

FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(fileContent))
{
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, "/ServerRelativeURL/" + 
fileInfo.Name, memoryStream, true);
}
}
```

But when I am trying to use `FileCreationInformation`, I get the 400 bad request error:

```
string siteUrl = "https://xxh.sharepoint.com/sites/my-Test-Site/";
string username = "xx@yy.com";
string password = "sad@fds";
string serverRelativeUrl = "Shared Documents/myFolder";
string filePath = "filePath.xlsx"

using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username,securePWD);

var fileCreationInfo = new FileCreationInformation
        {
            Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath),
            Overwrite = true,
            Url = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
        };

var targetFolder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);
var uploadFile = targetFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInfo);

context.Load(uploadFile);
context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Even if I simply want to run this code, I still get 400 bad request error.

```
List documentsLibrary = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
context.Load(documentsLibrary);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Or even just want to load the web like below, throws 400 bad request error.

```
        ClientContext context1 = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

        Web web = context1.Web;

        context1.Load(web);

        context1.ExecuteQuery();
```